# Can't post a Base64Image on IOS/Safari

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ios, html

I have got some script that gets an image from the first frame of a video and returns a base64image encoding.

I am then posting this image to the server back end to be saved to the uploads directory..

It works fine on chrome on a desktop, but when I test on iPhone7 IOS10 Safari it does not work.

I have tried to use both blobs and base64image but none work on iOS and both do work on chrome desktop.

Here is the javascript I'm currently using to get the image..

```
$('#upload').bind('change', function(event) {
        console.log("input");
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  if (file.type.match('image')) {
    fileReader.onload = function() {
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = fileReader.result;
      document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(img);
    };
    fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    fileReader.onload = function() {
      var blob = new Blob([fileReader.result], {type: file.type});
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      var video = document.createElement('video');
      var timeupdate = function() {
        if (snapImage()) {
          video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
          video.pause();
        }
      };
      video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
        if (snapImage()) {
          video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
        }
      });
      var snapImage = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
        canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        var image = canvas.toDataURL(); // Base64Image source

        var success = image.length > 100000;
        if (success) {
          var img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = image;
          document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(img);
          URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

           $.ajax({
    url : "uploadApi.php",
    type: "POST",
    data : {"videoThumb" : image},
    success: function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (data)
    {
 alert(data);
    }
});

          console.info("image");
          $('#b64image').val(image);
        }
        return success;
      };
      video.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
      video.preload = 'metadata';
      video.src = url;
      // Load video in Safari / IE11
      video.muted = true;
      video.playsInline = true;
      video.play();
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
});
```

**uploadApi.php**

```
var_dump($_POST["videoThumb"];
    $data = $_POST["videoThumb"];
    $videoId = 1;

            list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
            list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
            $data = base64_decode($data);

            $fileDirSrc = "../thumbs/"vid_".$videoId."_videoThumb.png";
            $fileDirSrcNoTrailingDots = "vid_".$videoId."_videoThumb.png";

         file_put_contents($fileDirSrc, $data);
```

Wierdly, the ajax response returns the dump of the base64image in an alert when on the desktop. But on iOS safari it returns **[object Object]**

You can try upload a video to his js fiddle, get an mp4 video file from http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5 first.

https://jsfiddle.net/jvftb0gt/2/